# htaccess redirect for old site url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

We have a client, where were building a new site.  There old system had all articles under:

http://www.domain.com/articles

The new site is

http://www.domain.com/resources/articles

Within the articles section url can be as long as:

http://www.domain.com/resources/articles/category-name/title-of-article

and there is

http://www.domain.com/resources/articles/page/# for the pagination

The new site will have the same url structure of the old articles except for the /resources part.

I need to have all incoming traffic that comes under:

http://www.domain.com/articles redirected to http://www.domain.com/resources/articles however I need to make sure that the category name and the title of the article in the url string are also placed in from the old string that was requested to the new one.

How can I do this using htaccess?

--- EDIT ---

Here is my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ?cat=$1&title=$2&subtitle=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) ?cat=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On your old site:**
Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(articles/.*)$  /resources/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: The old site and the new site are the same site.   Will this still work? Same site, same hosting - new design some url structure changes.

Comment: This causes a internal server error. I already have some code in the htaccess file I will update my post to include what i already have.

Comment: I had `RewriteRule` twice. Put this code right below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Hi - I tried but it seems everything on the site is trying to redirect to the resources..  I only need if /articles is after the www.domain.com when this redirects to /resources/articles.  So ideally, if someone puts domain.com/articles/some-thing/some-title it takes the /some-thing/some-title and redirects from /articles/some-thing/some-title to /resources/articles/some-thing/some-title.  Thanks for your time Anubhava!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31555/discussion-between-john-and-anubhava)